# Running Python script laravel php using shell_exec is slower than CLI

Tags: python, php, laravel

I have a simple Python script that prints "Hello World", and when I run it in CLI the execution time is just 0.05 ms but when I try to use the shell_exec in Laravel it takes around 1 sec.

```
$command = "python3 HelloWorld.py";
$esccommand = escapeshellcmd($command);
$output = shell_exec($esccommand);
```

I also tried with a Bash script it works just as fast as the command line, is it slow because it is in Python?

How can I make this faster?

Comment: You're asking php to launch a shell and then run your code, it makes sense that it would be longer to run is it not?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i understand, but is there any way to run python script in PHP that would be faster?

Comment: I suspect it's not slowing down the command itself it just adds 1 second to the startup... you could try with another (longer) code and I bet you'll see the difference between the two becomes small (but I'm no expert in this)